# How to work with a function that depends on another function's result using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, asynchronous, twitter

Let me explain my question in a better way:

I am building a TwitterBot that creates random images and tweets them. 
To do so, I have two functions in a NodeJS application, one called `createImage` and another called `tweetIt`

`createImage` creates a PNG file. 
`tweetIt` takes this image and, using the twitter API, tweets it.

So I have something like this:

```
function createImage(){
  //creates an image and saves it on disk
}

function tweetIt(){
  //takes the image from the disk and tweets it
}
```

I need to execute `createImage()` before `tweetIt()`, since the second function depends entirely on the result produced by the first.

```
createImage();
tweetIt();
```

But NodeJS executes them in parallel. How can I force one function to be completed before the execution of the second one? I tried some solutions I found here with callbacks and external packages but nothing worked. Someone here have any ideia of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Any reason why `tweetIt` can't just be invoked inside `createImage` once it has created an image?

Comment: You need to show us the code for `createImage()` so we can advise how to synchronize with the timing of when it's done (assuming it has some async operations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make createImage return a promise

```
function createImage(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // create image then resolve promise.
    // ...
    resolve()
  })
}

function tweetIt() {
  //takes the image from the disk and tweets it
}

createImage().then(tweetIt)
```

Comment: Oops, I meant `createImage().then(tweetIt)`.